# Print out the images stored in a mysqlite database

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I can print out all other information on the database (`name` and `bio`). But when I try to print out images, it comes as `image:????` in the eclipse terminal window.

I'm currently new to programming so I don't know how to go about this.

My code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.* ;  // for standard JDBC programs
import java.math.* ; // for BigDecimal and BigInteger support

public class Database {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

          Connection connection = null;
          ResultSet resultSet = null;
          Statement statement = null;

          try {
               Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
               connection = DriverManager
                         .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Mariam\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\info.sqlite");


               statement = connection.createStatement();
               resultSet = statement
                         .executeQuery("SELECT name, bio, image FROM PeoplesInfo");
               while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println("NAME:"
                              + resultSet.getString("name"));
                    System.out.println("Bio:"
                            + resultSet.getString("bio"));
                    System.out.println("Image:"
                            + resultSet.getString("Image"));

               }




          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
               try {
                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();
                    connection.close();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
          }
     }



}
```

Result:

```
NAME:James May
Bio:22, Working, 
Image:????
NAME:Lala
Bio:40, Working, etc
Image:????
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of data is in the `image` column? Strings? Blobs?

Comment: The data type is Blob

Comment: What do you want to display ? The image itself in Eclipse's console (hint: you can't) ? A binary/base64 version of the image ?

Comment: Yh i want to display it somehow even if i can't display it in the Terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get as a blob and then "convert to string", some thing simmilar to this:

```
Blob b = resultSet.getBlob("image");
byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
System.out.println(new String(bdata));
```

Comment: An image is not a string, even if you try to pretend otherwise …

Comment: True @CL., but from the questions. Above is what I understand the questioner wants. I might be wrong then :/

Comment: `getString` on a blob has the same effect as this code.

Comment: @CL. I will test that when I get home - But if I am wrong I am wrong